# Select distinct values from tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
student (id, name)
discipline (id, name)
student_discipline (stud_id, disc_id, mark)
```

I need to select everything from students where a student has 5 or more different disciplines with `mark > 4`

I have this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `student_discipline` a
LEFT JOIN `discipline` b ON a.disc_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN `student` c ON a.stud_id = c.id
WHERE a.mark > 4
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(b.id) >= 5
```

This sql gets every student that has promovated 5 or more diciplines but it takes all diciplines even if it's the same twice. I need to get distinct disciplines values. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying you have duplicate ID numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` in your `count()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `student_discipline` a
LEFT JOIN `discipline` b ON a.disc_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN `student` c ON a.stud_id = c.id
WHERE a.mark > 4
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct b.id) >= 5
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about the DISTINCT method but didn't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  c.id, c.name
FROM `student_discipline` a
LEFT JOIN `discipline` b ON a.disc_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN `student` c ON a.stud_id = c.id
WHERE a.mark > 4
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct b.id) >= 5
```